# F# on Mono for Android

Tags: android, f#, xamarin.android

I bought [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) from [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) and am very impressed so far except I would really like to use F# instead of C#. Has anyone managed to get F# running using this tool?

Comment: Good luck! It should work, and you should share with us your experience later :) I would've tried the trial before purchasing, but I guess that works.

Comment: There's a running thread about this on the fsharp-opensource group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fsharp-opensource/aUtrjy20pFE

Comment: Hey Jon, whats in the Mono for Android package, MonoDevelop and VS project templates and a few dlls?

Comment: @7sharp9 Android SDK, Windows drivers for devices, autoinstaller etc.

Answer (score 6):

Since F# has gone open-source you can compile the FSharp.Core.dll against the Mono framework.

The F# compiler source code is here http://fsharp.github.com/fsharp/

[Here](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FSharpAndroid&referringTitle=Home) are some instructions on how to get this working with Mono for Android

Basically you reference the Mono for Android mscorlib.dll and the FSharp.Core.dll that you compiled against the Mono framework from your F# project.